# How to setup modules for two PHP applications

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am trying to figure out how to upload 2 PHP applications to App Engine using the modules system.

The documentation is pretty lacklustre when it comes to explaining how to use modules for apps in their own subfolders.

Here is my folder stucture:

```
GOOGLE APP (root folder)
  |- main-app
    |- app.yaml
    |- source files
  |- api-module
    |- api-module.yaml
    |- source
```

(This kind of setup is outlined in a diagram on [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/#PHP_Application_hierarchy) page)

Is this correct?

And how exactly do I deploy this? The "appcfg" command needs an app.yaml file, but if I point it to the one inside the main-app folder, how will it pick up the api-module.yaml file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the module: stanza to your yaml files. You can then specify the paths of one or more of those files to appcfg.py when invoking update.

While it's a sensible practice, there's no requirement to have a common top level folder for your different modules (in fact all modules can share the same source if you want, but just described with different .yaml files)

There's also no requirement to update all modules at the same time.

Comment: Well I got it working by invoking appcfg update individually for the two yaml files.